# Is there a way to suppress cppclean issues?

Tags: c++

In most analysis tools you can suppress issues where you disagree with the tool. For example in cppcheck (not to be confused with cppclean) you can do:

```
// cppcheck-suppress <some-error-code>
int my_code_that_causes_cpp_check_error;
```

But I can't find any documentation on cppclean to do the same thing - is it possible and if so how?
Preferably I want to do this inline in the code because there are only very few specific cases where I want to shut it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From latest master branch find_warnings.py:

> TODO(nnorwitz): provide a mechanism to configure which warnings should
>   be generated and which should be suppressed. Currently, all possible
>   warnings will always be displayed. There is no way to suppress any.
>   There also needs to be a way to use annotations in the source code to
>   suppress warnings.

So, it appears not at the moment.